# how can I create a recursive algorithm that reverses the order of the values stored in the queue?

Tags: java, recursion, queue, logic, reverse

how can I create a recursive algorithm called reverse(Q) that reverses the order of the values stored in the queue while only using enqueue, dequeue, isEmpty? these are the only operations I use to manipulate the queue. I can’t use any type of loop, and without creating any additional data structure?

Q: 2 4 6 8 10 12 -------> reversed queue: 12 10 8 6 4 2

how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dequeue class from Java Library then you can proceed like below:

```
private static void reverse(Deque<Integer> q)
    {
        if(!q.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(q.pollLast()+" ");
            reverse(q);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without the dequeue class? only using dequeue method, enqueue method, and isEmpty method?

Comment: Actually, there is no predefined enqueue or dequeue method in java library.
If you are creating a custom Queue using array or list then you can declare these as queue methods.

Comment: what happens to an item that I dequeue from the queue? how can I call it again to insert it back into the queue?

Comment: if you don't want to remove the item from queue you can always use peek() but if you want to add it back then do removeLast() or pollLast() and save it in variable.
After that variable value you can again insert using add() so it will be added in the Last again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want your recursive function to first pop the front element out of the queue and call itself again *before* re-inserting the element. This way the first recursive call that actually gets to re-insert its newly popped element back is the last one.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100); // 100 is the queue's capacity
        q.add(1);
        q.add(2);
        q.add(3);
        q.add(4);
        Main.reverse(q);
        while (q.peek() != null) {
            System.out.println(q.remove());
        }
    }
    
    public static <T> void reverse(Queue<T> q) {
        if (q.peek() == null) {
            return;
        }
        T val = q.remove();
        reverse(q);
        q.add(val);
    }
}
```

Output

```
4
3
2
1
```